# Updating radius on google map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-maps, google-maps-react

I am trying to get the radius to change on my google map by fetching it from the database. For now I only get the "initial state" radius and after that it is hard to update it on the map overall. It is the same problem as updating the position of the user as well (I think). I am using Firebase, React and Javascript.

This is my map code:

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import Marker from './MapMarker';
import {getUserInfo} from '../firebaseConfig'

class SimpleMap extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lat: "",
    lng: "",
    userPos: "",
    radius: 1500
  };



  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 59.8,
      lng: 17.63889
    },
    zoom: 11,
  };



  componentDidMount = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.currentCoords)

  };


  currentCoords = (position) => {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude
    this.setState({
      userPos: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
    })
  };

  getRadius = () => {
    getUserInfo().then((result) => {
      this.setState({
        radius: result.radius
      })

      }); 
  }

  render() {

    const setCenter = this.state.userPos;
    const setUserPos = this.state.userPos;
    const setUserRadius = this.state.radius;


    const apiIsLoaded = (map, maps, setUserPos, setUserRadius) => {
      new maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        map,
        center: setUserPos,
        radius: setUserRadius
      });
    };

    return (
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: //key }}
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          center={setCenter}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
          yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
          onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiIsLoaded(map, maps, setUserPos, setUserRadius)}
        >
          <Marker
            lat={setUserPos.lat}
            lng={setUserPos.lng}
            color="blue"
          />

        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling the getRadius function? Can you check if the state of your radius is getting updated? It is possible that it is not being updated if you are only getting the initial value of the radius. Also, creating new circle inside `apiIsLoaded` and setting the value of its radius as the state of the radius won't change the circle radius this is because it will just create a circle with the initial value of your state radius. To be able to change the parameters of your circle such as its radius, you need to put it in a variable and change that variable every time the state changes.

Here's what I done:
First, make a global variable: `let circle;`

Then inside your apiIsLoaded put the circle object as the value of your circle variable:

```
circle = new maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        map,
        center: setUserPos,
        radius: setUserRadius
      });
```

Then in the function where you are changing the state of the circle, you need to put `circle.setRadius(this.state.radius)`. This will change the value of your circle's radius. So in your code, I can see that this is the function that change the state. Please see how I set the radius for the circle below:

```
getRadius = () => {
    getUserInfo().then((result) => {
      this.setState({
        radius: result.radius
      })
     
      }); 
   circle.setRadius(this.state.radius)
  }
```

Here's my [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/circle-change-radius-db5jwc?file=Map.js) and its code snippet below it is kinda different from yours since I just put the value of the radius and click the button to change its value.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import "./style.css";

let circle;
class GoogleMaps extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      center: { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 },
      inputRad: 100
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      inputRad: e.target.value
    });
  };
  changeRadius = () => {
    console.log(Number(this.state.inputRad));
    circle.setRadius(Number(this.state.inputRad));
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.inputRad)
    const apiIsLoaded = (map, maps) => {
      circle = new maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        map,
        center: this.state.center,
        radius: this.state.inputRad
      });
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%" }}>
          <input
            placeholder="Enter radius"
            type="number"
            min="100"
            name="inputRad"
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            value="Change circle radius"
            type="submit"
            onClick={this.changeRadius}
          />
          <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{
              key: "YOUR_API_KEY"
            }}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
            defaultZoom={15}
            center={this.state.center}
            yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
            onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiIsLoaded(map, maps)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleMaps;
```